# Displaying next data in Detailview of my NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, tableview, detailview

I have a simple problem.

Im using a NSMutableArray for multiple Questions and Answers. I`ve put all the data in a tableView and put the data of the selected row in a Label. Now, how do i get the data from the next row using a button? in think i need something like this:

```
   question.text = [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1];
```

But where to put it? If i use this line outside the cellForRowAtIndexPath Method it won't accept the indexPath.

I`m sure there is an easier way than this but with the words of Frank Sinatra: It is my way. :-)

Here is the complete methode:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView : (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {

return [questions count];

 }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"questionCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [questionTableView   
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
  reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if ([content.text isEqualToString:@"Unfallverhütung"]) {
    question.text = [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;
}
```

`question` is the Name of my Label.
`questions`is the Name of the Array.

I`m greatful for any advice.

THX

Comment: Why do you need the index path outside the method?

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> it won't accept the indexPath

What you mean is

> I don't have the indexPath

So, you need to store it. You can just add a property, like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it only works half way. If i use the following code:

question.text = [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1];

It gets me the data at row ONE. But i want it to jump to the next row.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you've added a property, and you're updating it each time a cell is selected?